# Is there a possible loop for this?

Tags: c#, loops, console, console-application

I just started to learn C# and only know really basic stuff. So this question may be easy to you, but very hard to me. The more detail in your answer, the better.

The next line of code will check if a studentnumber is real or fake. The number is real when the sum of all the characters (when multiplied by their place number) are a multiple of 11.

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your studentnumber?");
stnum = Console.ReadLine();

var stnumint = Convert.ToInt32(stnum);

var ans1 = (stnumint % 10 - stnumint % 1) / 1;
var ans2 = (stnumint % 100 - stnumint % 10) / 10;
var ans3 = (stnumint % 1000 - stnumint % 100) / 100;
var ans4 = (stnumint % 10000 - stnumint % 1000) / 1000;
var ans5 = (stnumint % 100000 - stnumint % 10000) / 10000;
var ans6 = (stnumint % 1000000 - stnumint % 100000) / 100000;
var ans7 = (stnumint % 10000000 - stnumint % 1000000) / 1000000;

var control = ans1 * 1 + ans2 * 2 + ans3 * 3 + ans4 * 4 + ans5 * 5 + ans6 * 6 + ans7 * 7;

var endnum = control % 11;

if (endnum == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have got a valid studentnumber.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Check if your studentnumber is correct. If it is, you are not a student.");
}
```

Take for example studentnumber 9232753. When calculating: (9*7 + 2*6 + 3*5 + 2*4 + 7*3 + 5*2 + 3*1) % 11,  the answer will be 0.

How can I write this line of code into a smaller loop?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Hint: What is 100 / 10, and 1000 / 100, and 10000 / 1000, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One equivalent loop would be:

```
int control = 0;
int power10 = 1;  // var to save an expensive `Math.Power` call
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    control += ((stnumint % (power10*10) - stnumint % power10) / power10) * i;
    power10 *= 10;
}
```

I would highly recommend *not* using `var` for built-in types like `int`, `string`, etc.  You leave the resulting type at the mercy of the compiler which can give you unexpected results.  Save `var` for when the *actual* type is difficult (or impossible) to determine at design-time.

Comment: I disagree with your advice about var. The type is determined only by the assignation after it. Use var if the type is evident at first glance (i.e. `var i = 1;`), use the actual type only if the code with var is not clear.

Make var the rule, not the exception. It will save a lot of time for you (and makes refactoring so much easier).

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalAns = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i *= 10)
{
    ans += (stnumint % (10*i) - stnumint % i) / i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part for calculation. If you need to save stnumint, copy it another variable.

```
int stnumint=...; //must be sure, that data type is n
int checksum=0;
int i=1;

while(stnumint>0)
{
    checksum=(stnumint%10)*i;
    i++;
    //in real numbers will look like floor(stnumint/10)
    //will automaticly floor because of data type int
    stnumint=stnumint/10;
}
```